# How to set a dynamic property on a model with Backbone.js

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, backbone.js

Story:
I have a lot of properties that needs to be set. Since they have similarities I choose to read out the class the inputbox is part of as property name.

Problem:
A dynamic property of an object can be set, just like an associative array. So I could do

```
var customattribute = this.$el.parents('div').attr('id');
var value = $(e.currentTarget()).val();

this.model.attributes[customattribute] = value;
```

But this wouldn't trigger a change event of the model. I could manually trigger a change event, but this wouldn't update this.model.changedAttributes(), I need to set only the changed attribute, not every attribute.

This of course doesn't work either:

```
this.model.set(customattribute: value);
```

*So how would I handle this problem?*

I have ALOT (200+) attributes that can be set, I wouldn't like to make separate eventlisteners for every attribute unless thats the only way.

Code:

```
var Display = Backbone.View.extend({
    className: 'display',
    events: {
        'slide .slider' : 'sliderHandler'
    },
    initialize: function(){
        _.bindAll(this, 'render', 'sliderHandler','update');
        this.model.on('change',this.update, this);
    },
    render: function(){
        this.$el.html(_.template(html, {}));
        this.$('.slider').slider();

        return this;
    },
    sliderHandler: function(e){
        var slider = $(e.currentTarget);
        var property = slider.parents('div').attr('id');
        var value = slider.slider('value');

        this.model.attributes[property] = value;            
    },
    update: function(){
        console.log(this.model.changedAttributes());
        //get changed attribute + value here

    },
});
```

Edit:

The two answers below solved it. Map the attributes to an object and give that to Backbone. Also I found another solution. Instead of an object, model.set() also accepts an array.

```
model.set(customattribute, value, customattribute2, value2);
```

Comment: Are you trying to propagate values from HTML elements to the backbone model when they change?

Comment: A user will fill in an input box or use a slider. When the value of either changes, I'll need to identify which of the 200 inputs he changed by reading out the DOM id. Using the value of the inputbox/slider and the DOM id $(e.currentTarget).parents('div').attr('id'), I update the model, which will update other views who listen to this model's change event.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I'm not sure that I fully understand your problem, but:
If you want to update an attribute, just:

```
this.model.set({
     customattribute: value
});
```

If you want that the setting not trigger an event, you could pass a silent option, like this:

```
this.model.set({
     customattribute: value
}, {silent:true});
```

I hope it helps you.

**UPDATED**:

Another way:

```
 var map = {};
 map[customattribute] = value;
 this.model.set(map);
```

Comment: the attribute would be called customattribute. For instance
    var customattribute = "test";
    this.model.set({customattribute: 12});

if you try to get the value:

    this.model.get("customattribute");

you'll get 12,

if you try 

this.model.get("test"); 

you will get undefined, and not 12

Comment: using an associted array, you could do what you want. I updated in order to give you an example. Again, if you don't want to fire an event, pass the option: silent:true.

Answer (score 5):

You need to do this

```
var attributeName = this.$el.parents('div').attr('id');
var value = $(e.currentTarget()).val();
var attribute = {};
attribute[attributeName] = value;
this.model.set(attribute);
```

if attribute was "test" and value 'value' it would be the same as

```
this.model.set({test: 'value'});
```

which is what correctly sets the attribute and propagates to your view thanks to model change event

Answer (score 0):

As of [Backbone 0.9.0 (Jan. 30, 2012)](http://backbonejs.org/#changelog), [`model.set`](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-set) ([source](https://github.com/jashkenas/backbone/blob/5ce976bf6a6c795e295190bcc48c39e52f9afe6f/backbone.js#L214)) accepts a **key**, a **value**, and an **options** object.

```
this.model.set(attributeName, value, { silent: true });
```

is equivalent to

```
var attr = {};
attr[attributeName] = value;
this.model.set(attr, { silent: true });
```